# Where can I find the first text that loads in the Python shell and change it?

Tags: python

This text loads when I open IDLE or load Python in cmd:

> Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600
>   32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()"
>   for more information.

Where can I find the file and change the text or make a script load instead?

Comment: hahaha, That's hilarious, But why do you wanna do that ?

Comment: Haha glad you like it... I just thought it would be cool to be greeted by something like "Welcome master."

Comment: You can see the `idlelib` source code: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/293d9964cf6e/Lib/idlelib

Comment: See also e.g. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/293d9964cf6e/Lib/code.py#l209

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to *change* the default text without modifying/recompiling the python binary, but it seems you can use the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` in order to add additional text via a python file with `print` commands. You can also change the prompt strings in this file. For example:

in my .bashrc:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/jake/.mypythonstartup
```

/home/jake/.mypythonstartup:

```
import sys
print("Welcome, master!")
sys.ps1 = "How may I serve you? "
sys.ps2 = "                 ... "
```

Result:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Welcome, master!
How may I serve you? def test():
                 ...     print("test")
                 ...
How may I serve you? test()
test
How may I serve you?
```

Documentation on `PYTHONSTARTUP` can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#the-interactive-startup-file

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick snoop around the [`idlelib` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/293d9964cf6e/Lib/idlelib), you could do something like:

```
from code import interact
interact("Welcome master.")
```

In use:

```
$ python idle2.py
Welcome master.
>>> print 'foo'
foo
```

---

You could also use the [command line flags](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) to run a command then enter interactive mode:

```
$ python -ic "print 'Welcome master.'"
Welcome master.
>>>
```